# Charset works in php but not in HTML

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I am having a strange issue. I have Swedish characters. My charset works fine when in loop and being pulled from mysql using PHP but when I simply enter HTML text Swedish character Å, Ä and Ö it does not work. Currently this is my set Charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

Here is a picture of how it looks in the browser:

[image]

Now here is a picture of data being pulled from Mysql (in loop) on the same page:

[image]

If this question has been asked before, please direct me to the page. Could it be somethign to do with the actual page encoding?

Comment: try using charset="UTF-8" in meta tag

Comment: That changes my HTML but the PHP data does not work then.

Comment: check charset/collation of the db table

Comment: try using PHP utf8_decode() or mysql_set_charset() function

Comment: what do you mean "your php data does not work then"?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file itself ist stored in `UTF-8`.Try and save it as a `ANSI` file.
In `notepad++` this can be done via `Encoding > Encode in ANSI` in the menubar.
Or try to change the meta tag as already suggested.